Некорректно разделяется docx файл
Нужно вставить содержимое файла for_copy_path в файл template_path в строчку где написано {{ FOR_PASTE }}. В обоих файлах находиться необходимое форматирование, которое нужно сохранить.
Перепробовал кучу вариантов, из которых остановился на разделение docx файла на два в нужном месте (где {{ FOR_PASTE }}) и вставкой другого файла между ними с помощью docxcompose.composer. Но колонтитулы в файле template_path плывут и добавляются некорректно.
import tempfile
from typing import Generator, Tuple
from docx import Document
from docx.document import Document as DocType
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.oxml.xmlchemy import BaseOxmlElement
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from docxcompose.composer import Composer

template_path = r'Dockx\\shablon.docx'
output_path1 = r'Dockx\\result1.docx'
output_path2 = r'Dockx\\result2.docx'
for_copy_path = r'Dockx\\text_for_copy.docx'
output_path = r'Dockx\\result.docx'


def iterparts(doc_path: str, split_text: str) -> Generator[Tuple[int, DocType], None, None]:
    """Iterate over sub-documents by splitting source document into parts."""
    doc = Document(doc_path)
    split_elem_idx = -1
    doc_body = doc.element.body
    for idx, elem in enumerate(doc_body.iterchildren()):
        if is_split_point(elem, split_text):
            split_elem_idx = idx
            break
    if split_elem_idx != -1:
        yield split(doc, split_elem_idx)
    else:
        yield (doc, None)


def is_split_point(element: BaseOxmlElement, split_text: str) -> bool:
    """Check if the element is the split point."""
    if isinstance(element, CT_P):
        p = Paragraph(element, element.getparent())
        return split_text in p.text
    return False


def split(doc: DocType, cut_idx: int) -> Tuple[DocType, DocType]:
    """Split the document into two parts at the given index."""
    tmpdocfile = write_tmp_doc(doc)
    second_part = doc
    second_elems = list(second_part.element.body.iterchildren())
    for i in range(0, cut_idx + 1):
        remove_element(second_elems[i])

    first_part = Document(tmpdocfile)
    first_elems = list(first_part.element.body.iterchildren())
    for i in range(cut_idx, len(first_elems)):
        remove_element(first_elems[i])

    tmpdocfile.close()
    return (first_part, second_part)


def write_tmp_doc(doc: DocType) -> tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile:
    """Write the document to a temporary file."""
    tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    doc.save(tmpfile.name)
    return tmpfile


def remove_element(elem):
    """Remove an element from its parent."""
    parent = elem.getparent()
    parent.remove(elem)


def save_doc_parts(template_path: str, split_text: str):
    parts = list(iterparts(template_path, split_text))
    if parts:
        first_part, second_part = parts[0]
        if first_part:
            first_part.save(output_path1)
        if second_part:
            second_part.save(output_path2)
        # Открытие документов
        template1 = Document(output_path1)
        template2 = Document(output_path2)
        for_copy = Document(for_copy_path)
        # Создание композитного документа
        composer = Composer(template1)
        composer.append(for_copy)
        composer.append(template2)
        # Сохранение результата
        composer.save(output_path)


# Вызов основной функции
save_doc_parts(template_path, "{{ FOR_PASTE }}")

Файлы: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mXuKeaW7phb3iWWZ7QDZJRv_G-W406KY/view
Вот как плывёт колонтитул (слева шаблон, справа результат):
